# Coding Style Guide for node.js apps?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, node.js

Is there a (or several) coding style guide for node.js? If not, what are the **emerging styles** used by the top open-source node projects?

I'm looking for a guide (or several guides) along the lines of [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the canonical Coding Style Guide for Python. I've seen various JavaScript guides not worth linking here (mostly old and targeted at client-side JavaScript). I found one interesting node.js [style guide](http://nodeguide.com/style.html).

A coding style guide, or coding conventions, should include (but is not limited to):

- Code layout: indentation (2 spaces, 4 spaces, tabs, ...), newlines, line breaks, etc.
- Whitespace, e.g., "function (arg)" vs. "function(arg)"
- Semicolon or no semicolon, var declaration, ...
- Naming, e.g., do_this() vs. doThis(), var_name vs. varName, ...
- node.js and JavaScript idioms, e.g., == vs. ===, callback's first arg is an error object, ...
- Comments and documentation
- Accompanying tools, like lint checker, unit test framework, ...

This topic obviously is highly subjective, but I think it's an important step of a community to establish a common and widely accepted coding style in the process of getting mature. Also, it's not all just about taste. In particular, rules like "use === instead of ==" have a direct influence on code quality.

Comment: i gues it realy depends on the "framework" you use ( if any ), for example you could check out http://spludo.com/source/coding-standards/ however others might concider slightly different aproaches

Comment: "Does anybody have a good set of style guides" may or may not be subjective, but "What are the emerging styles" certainly is. You've already found Felix's guide, which of course I disagree with aspects of (in some cases strongly) and agree with other aspects of. And that's the problem. Very, very quickly it gets into "No, the style **I'm** seeing emerge uses tabs!" "No, the style *I'm* seeing emerge uses four spaces!" "No, the style ***I'm*** seeing emerge uses *two* spaces!" When, of course, what people really mean is "the style I prefer", not "the style I'm seeing emerge."

Comment: @T.J. Croweder The style _I'm_ seeing emerge uses no spaces!

Comment: +1 Awesome question. I wish I had these links ages ago.

Comment: Subjective question.

Comment: With the risk of contradicting myself, I can see how the accepted (as well as currently highest voted) answer is actually problematic from an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) point of view. Maybe this has to do with ***how*** the question was asked rather than the topic (style guides / coding-style)? Or maybe not? "**DO NOT USE! This tag refers to an entirely opinionated subject and is therefore no longer on-topic.** Questions that follow coding style and conventions." - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/coding-style/info. |  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/coding-style/synonyms

Comment: Concerning whether to reopen this question or not. I just had a discussion with TylerH in the comments of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315208 which I believe is relevant for such a decision.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

I'd review the coding standards checked by [JSLint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/) or look at the author of [NPM](https://github.com/isaacs/npm) (Isaac Shlueter's) [coding standards](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/coding-style).

You could also look at the style used by notable Node.JS coders:

- [TJ Holowaychuk](https://github.com/visionmedia)
- [Isaac Shlueter](https://github.com/isaacs)
- [Tim Caswell](https://github.com/creationix)
- [Jeremy Ashkenas](https://github.com/jashkenas)
- [Felix Geisendörfer](https://github.com/felixge)
- [Charlie Robbins](https://github.com/indexzero)
- [Marak Squires](https://github.com/Marak)
- [Aaron Heckmann](https://github.com/aheckmann)
- [Guillermo Rauch](https://github.com/guille)
- [Mikeal Rogers](https://github.com/mikeal)
- [Ryan Dahl](https://github.com/ry) + you could look at [the actual Node.JS codebase](https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/master/lib)

I'll [throw mine](http://github.com/chriso) in there for good measure ;)

Edit: Suggestions from [@alienhard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389442/alienhard)

- [Google JavaScript style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml)
- [Felix's Node.js Style Guide](https://github.com/felixge/node-style-guide)

IMO there's a few golden rules you should follow:

- Never use `with` or `eval`
- Use `===` over `==`
- Always declare your variables with `var` in the appropriate scope - don't fallback to the global scope
- Wrap your app in a closure `(function(){})()` if you plan on releasing code that runs server-side as well as in the browser
- Callbacks should take `err` as the first argument and if they themselves take a callback as an argument, it should be last, e.g. `callback(err, param1, param2, callback)`

Indentation, spacing between braces and keywords and semicolon placement are all a matter of preference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering why you didn't mention Ryan ;). But I figured, from the official node repo wiki, that they follow [Google’s JavaScript style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml). I didn't knwo that one before...

Answer (score 21):

There's a new standard in town.

Use [Standard Style](https://github.com/feross/standard).

[image: js-standard-style]

Comment: I have no idea why this has only 3 upvotes...

Comment: @Luc maybe because of the "No semicolons" rule. Seems like an odd choice for something called the "Standard" style.

Comment: No semicolons is not a good idea. It will break some minification.

Comment: This `standard` package doesn't like semicolons. If you like semicolons there is [semistandard](https://github.com/standard/semistandard)

Answer (score 10):

You can learn a lot of good coding style practices from client side oriented JavaScript guides (most of them apply also to node.js in general since the difference between client and server side is mostly in libraries and not in language itself). For example [JavaScript Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596806767) book dedicates to this topic some parts of the [Chapter 2](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9781449399115/essentials/essentials). Also Douglas Crockford's [website](http://javascript.crockford.com/), [book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748) and [videos](http://yuiblog.com/crockford/) are a must see materials in order to adopt JavaScript specific coding styles and best practices I would say.

Comment: +1 to Douglas Crockford's book "JavaScript: The Good Parts". It's got a hell of a lot of information in a concise / small book - a heavy read, but one of the best books I've read.

Answer (score 7):

When using node from the terminal, it's useful for your source code to use spaces for indentation. Otherwise, the "error here" caret won't line up.

With tabs:

```
        var preps = files.map(function(f) { 
            ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of null
```

With spaces:

```
        var preps = files.map(function(f) { 
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of null
```

This might be a Mac only issue, but I would suspect not.

Comment: OP asked for a style guide. Not some specific tip.

Comment: @mightyiam True, but indentation rules are a part of almost every style guide. Maybe my point can help OP evaluate some of the style guides that others will link, or can help him develop his own style guide.

Answer (score 6):

It has been a while since I asked this question... and in the meantime I've found this excellent JavaScript guide:

**Principles of Writing Consistent, Idiomatic JavaScript**

https://github.com/rwldrn/idiomatic.js/

Answer (score 5):

Airbnb has a quite good Javascript style guide
https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

Answer (score 2):

For Coffee-Script, where bad indents means compilation errors

use

```
:set tabstop=2
:set shiftwidth=2
:set expandtab
```

popular coffee projects, `zombie`, `brunch` uses this setup for indentations.

Edit:

Actually, just use this! https://github.com/paulmillr/code-style-guides (one of the main contributors to `brunch`)