# JavaScript style recommendations

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I know that the golden rules for formating code are clarity and consistency. I have found a few tips and words of advice in Crockford's book, but no real reference thoroughly discussing the issue.

Is there an online reference or book that goes through code style (tabulation, spacing, line breaks, comments, etc.) in a consistent and methodic way?

Comment: Relevant [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495984/coding-style-guide-for-node-js-apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specific to Javascript, but I've yet to see a book that handles code style (which can be applied to any language) better than [Robert Martin's Clean Code](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=robert%20martin%27s%20clean%20code&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882&ei=zFWoTuiBMoeniQL77cm-DQ&usg=AFQjCNHR62yE9_f-EXjfGyx8aKcovzjKHw&cad=rja).

Comment: For more on this topic, consider Knuth's Literate Programming. It's a bit dated, but Donald is a bit of a joy. http://www.literateprogramming.com/

Answer (score 1):

Nothing I have seen.  However, this might give you some ideas: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 1):

Check out Douglas Crockford's [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read the book but here is a good code conventions guide by Crockford:

http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Sticking to coding conventions alone doesn't guarantee clarity and style. Clarity will come from how you structure your application, so I guess that is really a measure of how experienced or how good a code writer you are. If you are using a library such as Prototype or JQuery then you'd be best to study their specific recommended best practives.

Answer (score 1):

Google JavaScript Style Guide:[link](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml)

The mentioned crockford: [link](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)

Comment: That Apple guide is chock full of bad advice. I would not recommend it.

Comment: @CarstenHeisterkamp: Could you add it back just for future reference?

Comment: Sure: Apples JS Coding standard [link](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=apple%20javascript%20coding%20style%20guide&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sourceformat.com%2Fpdf%2Fjavascript-coding-standard-apple.pdf&ei=HVeoTrvGG4SSswa02bnDDQ&usg=AFQjCNHjFZXUD1iDiL6ZuGwd6SfEg4EMag&sig2=yNtb0NCclKxjcnKX-ZPZ7g&cad=rja)

Apple took it from their developer site and it seems that many people pointed out that it is a horrible doc, which I didnt know.