# What is the JSON indentation level convention?

Tags: javascript, json

Is there any such thing as the "standard" convention for JSON indentation level? Should it be 2 spaces, 3 spaces, 4 spaces, tabs delimited, or something else?

I tried to come across [the official JSON site](http://www.json.org/), but it is not stated there.

Comment: There is no such convention. Often, JSON is sent in minimal form (minimal space like characters).

Comment: @jenson-button-event too many people, unfortunately :(

Comment: From the page you linked to: *"Whitespace can be inserted between any pair of tokens."* So no, there is no such convention.

Comment: @Alnitak And unfortunately, I am one of them. :( I handcraft it for my configuration file. So, it's not the right thing?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

JSON is a *serialization* format, not a *presentation* format.

As such, there is no "standard" indentation - JSON is typically sent as compactly as possible.

(That said, there is an option to `JSON.stringify()` to request "pretty printed" JSON - look at the `space` parameter at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify))

Comment: I see. But what if I'm using JSON as a configuration format (e.g. in a config file)? Should I use my "own" standard indentation for this purpose or there already exists any "common" standard?

Comment: there's no common standard, just use whatever looks good for your requirements - the JSON parser will ignore the extra white space.

Answer (score 23):

There is no standard. The [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/) permits any number of whitespaces.

However, when you are pretty-printing JSON to make it readable (e.g. in config files) it is good practise to be consistent with the coding conventions of your project and use the same indendation level as you would for an JS object literal - which is often 4 ([Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#indentation)) or 2 spaces ([Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5495984/1048572)).

Comment: do not conflate Crockford's _coding guidelines_, with Crockfords _formatting guidelines_.  The former are good, the latter are, umm, a crock of dogma and his personal preference.

Comment: @Alnitak: Sure, but 4 spaces are quite standard for JS code; I seldom see 8 or 2 spaces or a tab for indentation. Crockford was just the first link I found… Going to edit.

Comment: Tab size can be subjectively specified, is intended for indentation, and as such uses fewer bytes than most spaces conventions.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman yes. And then you get into a nightmare with your SCM generating a whole bunch of changes and people wasting hours of their life changing spaces to tabs or visa versa.  There's a good reason that many / most IDEs replace tabs with spaces by default!  Honestly nobody cares about the number of bytes their json files take up in a git repo.  They do care when someone comes along and screws up the formatting.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Just ignore white space changes.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Then autoformat the code using the Prettier standard.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Nobody suggested to use a mix of tabs and spaces, or waste time changing one into the other. Just decide on one and keep that (and there are many tools to help you with keeping your files consistent). But both choices are equally legitimate and valid.

Comment: @Bergi you missed the point.  If you settle on white space (default for most IDEs) then it's very rare for someone new to mess it up. if you settle on tabs (as was common 20 years ago) its *very* common for someone to mess it up.  Cees Timmerman appeared to suggest this could be fixed by just "ignoring white space changes", or using it autoformatting tools.  It can't.  It get's messed up and people waste their life fixing it.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I can't see that, I've had both tab-only and space-only codebases messed up by noobs - they just need to be told once to follow the convention and use the tooling configuration from the repo. I think Cees referred to "*your SCM generating a whole bunch of changes*" with his comment. Btw, both spaces and tabs are white space :-)

Comment: @bergi feel free to disagree. My experience has been as I've stated (in recent years) due to the default behaviour of modern IDEs. ... I'd assumed he meant that RE the SCM which is why I pointed out it would leave a mix.