# How to start with a JavaScript coding style?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, code-standards, standardjs

How can I learn or start learning the right coding style in JavaScript? What are my possibilities and what practical resources can I use to get used to the coding style? Thanks!

```
var getRequestUserList = function getRequestUserList(req,res,id) {
    User.findOne({_id: id}, function (err, user,next) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    if(user){
        var userList = [];
        User.find(function (err, users) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            if(users){
                Friend.find({getReq:id,status:0 }, function (err, friends) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }else{
                        for (var i = 0;i< users.length;i++){
                            for(var j = 0;j<friends.length;j++){
                                if(users[i]._id == friends[j].sendReq){
                                    userList.push({
                                        id : users[i]._id,
                                        name : users[i].name,
                                        surname : users[i].surname,
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        res.json({friendUser:userList});
```

Comment: You can follow there standards to style your code: http://jshint.com/

Comment: What is your question and how is that code relevant to it?

Comment: Thats like *writing style*. You cant really learn it. Develop your own by writing a lot...

Comment: I recommend StandardJS, it's painless, no configuration, easy to use and install, check out my answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495984/coding-style-guide-for-node-js-apps/28954080#28954080

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to install and use [**StandardJS**](https://standardjs.com/). It's an easy to use, hassle-free coding style.

Install it via:

```
npm install standard --save-dev
```

Then run [**through the rules**](https://standardjs.com/rules.html) just to quickly get a feel of it.

Finally, create a **script in your package.json** to run StandardJS, when you need it:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "check": "standard"
  }
}
```

...then you can run it via `npm run check`

---

To provide a quick way to yourself to fix most coding style typos, add a **fix script to your package.json**:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "check": "standard",
    "fix": "standard --fix"
  }
}
```

...and run via `npm run fix`

---

To get a more **nicer representation** of coding style errors, install **snazzy** via `npm install snazzy --save-dev`, then modify your package.json like so:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "check": "standard --verbose | snazzy",
    "fix": "standard --fix"
  }
}
```

---

### Just code as much as you can. After a while, you'll get the hang of the coding style of your choice.

#### Good luck, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

There are code styles like [jshint.com](http://jshint.com) or [standardJS](https://standardjs.com/) which also include automatic code formatting.